# AYUDA EN JAVA, ejercicio sin usar operadores relacionales

Tags: java

PROBLEMA: Se debe ingresar por teclado 3 numeros enteros positivos y presentarlos por pantalla de forma descendente. Es decir, desde el mayor al menor. Se debe evitar el uso de los operadores relacionales(menor que, mayor que, meno o igual que, mayor o igual que)

Necesita una ayuda con este problema ya que no se como sacar el mayor de un numero sin usar operadores de relacion, alguna ayuda :( todo esto en lenguaje java

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: todo lo que e intentado necesariamente se debe utilizar operadores relacionales :(

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y por favor añade algo de eso que has intentado

Comment: Aparte de la recomendación anterior, por favor no agregues etiquetas de lenguajes que no estén relacionados a la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías almacenar los números enteros en un Arraylist y utilizar el método .sort de la clase Collections que te los ordena, y no tienes que utilizar operadores relacionales. Acá un ejemplo:

```
public class OrdenarArrays {

Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList <Integer> enteros = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public OrdenarArrays(){
    System.out.println("Escriba el primer entero: ");
    enteros.add(lector.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Escriba el segundo entero: ");
    enteros.add(lector.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Escriba el tercer entero: ");
    enteros.add(lector.nextInt());
    Collections.sort(enteros);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < enteros.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println("Los números ingresados, ordenados de manera ascendente son: " + enteros.get(i));
    }
}
```

Edito porque acabo de darme cuenta que tu pregunta era para hacerlo de manera descendente.
La diferencia es que tendrás que crear un objeto de la clase Comparator para que compare los elementos y los ponga en orden inverso. Aquí el mismo ejemplo modificado:

```
public class OrdenarArrays {

Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList <Integer> enteros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Comparator<Integer> comparador = Collections.reverseOrder();

public OrdenarArrays(){
    System.out.println("Escriba el primer entero: ");
    enteros.add(lector.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Escriba el segundo entero: ");
    enteros.add(lector.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Escriba el tercer entero: ");
    enteros.add(lector.nextInt());
    Collections.sort(enteros, comparador);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < enteros.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println("Los números ordenados de manera descendente: " + enteros.get(i));
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new OrdenarArrays();
}
```

}